# What does Bad EIP value error means?

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I've been writing some kernel module recently. For some modules everytime i insert them or remove them a huge kernel trace is shown on screen. The errors are somewhat like

```
 ERROR: Bad EIP value.
```

or

```
ModuleName is tainted.
```

What does this imply. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe you should post code of module which create this problem.

Comment: Also looking in google "bad eip value kernel module" does show some possible articles that would help you. Sometimes google is better than SO.

Answer (score 0):

The Extended Instruction Pointer exists in x86 processors, but is somehow related to a missing WiFi driver, [it seems:](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=83952)

> Yesterday I could not reach this site and read your reactions, so I
>   experimented with several Linux versions: Xubuntu, Slacko-Puppy 5,4
>   Firefox ,Puppy Akita Beta and LinuxMintMaya. And with all the same
>   result, i.e. no result,
>
> But in the last install - LinuxMintMaya - I discovered the problem,
>   which is be found here: http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_maya.php  It
>   tells:
>
> Boot hangs on systems using b43 wireless cards
>
> So after entering this command
>
> Code: `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
>
> LinuxMintMaya works.

To boot, the Mint page says:

> An upstream issue in the kernel prevents Linux Mint 13 from booting on
>   computers with b43 wireless cards. If you're in this situation, try
>   the following:
>
> To boot the live DVD, choose the "Compatibility mode" or add the
>   following kernel argument to the boot options: `b43.blacklist=yes`
>   Install Linux Mint on the hard drive If not present already, in Grub,
>   modify the boot options to add: `b43.blacklist=yes` Install the b43
>   firmware on the system